# fullscreen using multimonitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I've got a laptop with an extra external screen attached to it. Whenever I try to maximize a window on the second screen by dragging it to the top of it the window maximizes to my laptop screen. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: It works as expected for me, it maximizes the window to the screen where I move the window. Could it be a video driver problem (I have Intel video card)?.

Comment: This 5+ year old unanswered question would be about Ubuntu 12.04 (EOL) or an earlier version which is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows maximize in the wrong display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214441/windows-maximize-in-the-wrong-display)