# Windows maximize in the wrong display

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, window

I use dual display with Ubuntu 12.04.

Display 1: Thinkpad T420s. Intel HD3000
Display 2: HP 1955.

Whenever I want to maximize the windows (say a Chrome browser) in display 1, it automatically goes to display 2.

I tried several ways to maximize a windows (shortcut, maximize button, mouse drag-to-top) and it's resulting the same.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/52716/maximize-windows-to-physical-screen-when-using-a-virtual-resolution-w-xrandr ?

Comment: Do you experience this problem with other programs, not just Chrome?

Answer (score 6):

The comment to the other answer is the best solution:

> It's apparently a bug of Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04.
>   Workaround: instead of maximizing Google Chrome using the maximize button or drag-to-top on display 1, do the following: 1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> 2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

So to maximize Google Chrome, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: Interestingly enough, clicking the maximize button works properly for me, but using Ctrl+Super+Left, Ctrl+Super+Up  causes this problem for me (though, for me, it happens with multiple workspaces rather than multiple screens).

Answer (score 0):

Install `ccsm` (`compizconfig-settings-manager`) and enable the "*place windows*" plugin. You can force a window to be placed at specific pixel top/left.

There's also *General options > Display settings*. You can add your monitors' width x height and/or set *Overlapping Output Handler* to prefer screen with mouse pointer.

Comment: couldn't figure it out with your suggestion. However, it only affected Google chrome but works perfectly with the rest (Chromium, Nautilus, Document viewer)

Comment: It apparently a bug of Google chrome on ubuntu 12.04,

workround:

instead of maximizing Google chrome by maximize button or drag-to-top on display 1, do the followings:

1. ctrl+super+left
2. ctrl+super+up

Comment: @Husni Huge thanks for the last one. After I used it one time the bug was gone. It was happening in chromium and firefox